# Create an Arm Navigation Pkg

Tags: ros, arm-navigation, tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I used this tutorial:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/Industrial/Tutorials/Create_a_Arm_Nav_Pkg_for_an_Industrial_Robot

to generate arm navigation pkg for two hands that i use in gazebo.
i have now the configuration from the wizard, how do i configure it to use a controller that i already have for this hands? and how to test it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50056/create-an-arm-navigation-pkg/) by [nir](https://answers.ros.org/users/3001/nir/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2012-12-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

Are you talking about two multi-DOF hands, or two separate multi-DOF manipulators with hands at the end?

Yes there are some gaps in the documentation.
You should read all the normal ROS arm_navigation tutorials, and also the ROS industrial ones.
Also use Google to search site:ros.answers.org for everything related to arm_navigation, joint_trajectory_action & follow_joint_trajectory.

If you followed the tutorials, you should be able to load your robot model in the planning warehouse viewer, plan trajectories, smooth them and watch the trajectory.

Once you've got that far, you need to load a node like follow_joint_trajectory that receives the trajectory messages and sends it to your controller.  If you're using Gazebo then you might be able to use the ROS/PR2 controllers for following the trajectory and controlling the joint positions.

Feel free to contribute your own documentation :-)

---

Originally posted by [dbworth](https://answers.ros.org/users/2571/dbworth/) with karma: 1103 on 2012-12-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nir](https://answers.ros.org/users/3001/nir/) on 2012-12-19**:
hi, found out that i get this error: "Planning scene not set". i tried: rosservice call /environment_server/set_planning_scene_diff '{}'   but it didn't work.